# Why am I getting this error "Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'" while parsing JSOn data in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I want to display the youtube thumbnails list as a banner list in my app in Page view.
I parsed the Json data using a video on youtube but I am getting an exception "Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'"

I shall put down everything I have done and put a small explanation

```
{
  "home_banners": [
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_LnNcjFpILQA",
      "title": "Andhadhun",
      "tags": [
        "Crime",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfe2923885a21499490b"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWZhMjhhZmYtOTIzOC00MGYzLWI1OGYtM2ZkN2IxNTI4ZWI3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAzNDk0MTQ@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LnNcjFpILQA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.613849"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_jzKGrOGnERc",
      "title": "Madaari",
      "tags": [
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZDFjODM0NDAtNGJkZC00NmRiLWI3NmYtZDFkYmRhYmE4Zjk3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIwODMzNjc@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jzKGrOGnERc/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:33.318952"
    },
    
   
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_886EXj5MXl0",
      "title": "Rakht Charitra 1",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Biography",
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7",
        "5e10bfe2923885a21499490b"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDU1NjAxNTMxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDUzMjk4NTE@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/886EXj5MXl0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.000245"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_lz1N4r7SGrY",
      "title": "Satyamev Jayate",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzYxNGI3MmYtMWQyMi00NmViLWE0ZWQtNWM5ZTY3NTIxNzU0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODE5NzE3OTE@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/lz1N4r7SGrY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:33.404778"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_Pwidjiomr9w",
      "title": "Mohejo Daaro",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "History"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzBhNTk0MzUtZTc4Yy00NDk3LWE1ZTItYjFmODQ4NTczMGVkL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDkxMzY0Mjk@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Pwidjiomr9w/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.666504"
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLcvCQa6KHYRkR01iUhrTy-Ng0sDy5G3bk",
      "title": "A.I.SHA My Virtual Girlfriend",
      "tags": [
        "Thrillers"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfe1923885a214994908"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDM0MWRiNWMtMDUxMi00M2Y5LThkYzUtMjkwYmE0ZWE5YTZhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjY2Mzk3Mzg@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/X3flTlvbfBE/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.378572"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PL4x7Of-X4XhiK_gmCcJF8xfrlQN_46nmj",
      "title": "What the Folks",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fc"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZWM4YWYxYjEtZDU1Yi00NjIzLTkwYTItMGQ4MThjNDA2ZDFkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDAzNDk0MTQ@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1rQJXDGc6OY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.163742"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLxY80KSzpL2NoLLzmWHUJEHk3_J1eWJWw",
      "title": "Bachelors",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fc"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTc2M2U0NDUtNjgzMC00YmI5LTlmOTktZTZlMGRkYTNiODNhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzEyNTM4MTU@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5XuimeH5hME/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.416601"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLjq6DwYksrzz_fsWIpPcf6V7p2RNAneKc",
      "title": "The Age of A.I.",
      "tags": [
        "Documentary"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948fe"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMmE3Y2M4YzYtOWRhZS00OTA2LTgyZDUtYTA4MTBkNTRmNThiXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjUxMjc1OTM@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UwsrzCVZAb8/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 1.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.385511"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "discoveryplus_jamies-quick-and-easy-food",
      "title": "Jamie's Quick and Easy Food",
      "tags": [
        "Food"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948fe"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNGI0ZjZlYTktYzk2OC00MmQwLTgwMmUtYTM2MGZkYTYwNDIyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODc4MDI5MjI@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://ap2-prod-images.disco-api.com/2020/03/06/afecc471-5ad6-4770-bd79-ee5928bda612.jpeg?bf=0&f=jpg&p=true&q=75&w=600",
      "platform": "discoveryplus",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:02.745905"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLZFXeozdia12APH8n9xsVNhd5qallmrz2",
      "title": "The Katering Show",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fc"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTU4NjU4NDQwOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTIyNjk1NDE@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J55vgxNaaBY/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 1.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.280574"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLTB0eCoUXErb7pV0Sj1hXWrxerSZX1qgh",
      "title": "Kota Factory",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fc",
        "5e10bfdf923885a214994900"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWFlNTY5MzEtNDhhMy00YTRmLWJhYjMtM2JjODkyMGRkZmUzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyOTAzMTc2MjA@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JWbnEt3xuos/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.283542"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "discoveryplus_morgan-freemans-through-the-wormhole",
      "title": "Morgan Freeman's Through the Wormhole",
      "tags": [
        "Science"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948fe"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDhkMTY2NGQtMWY4Mi00ZjhmLWIzNGYtZDJhODkwNTM5NTIzXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDk3NDEzMzk@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://ap2-prod-images.disco-api.com/2020/03/04/0bc1cb72-2899-4b5c-b36e-fff7e4ecba6a.jpeg?bf=0&f=jpg&p=true&q=75&w=600",
      "platform": "discoveryplus",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:02.742655"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLGzz7pyosmlJfx9ivigemSouoZR9uLT2-",
      "title": "Minus One",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fc"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNWU2YWIwYjAtZGEyMS00ZDk1LWFmZWMtOTU1NzMxZGZiMjhjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTc2NTE3MDM@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iyL9-EE3ngk/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.209943"
    },
    {
      "series_id": "youtube_PLcUQLQkgCREYaBc7S_b8Zp0HNJsciE9bA",
      "title": "Mom and Co",
      "tags": [
        "Drama"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a214994900"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmQ1NjEyYmYtODFjZi00ZWZmLTg0NzEtNTRmNTliMjc2ZTVjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzI3MjU2MTg@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tPQ85zH-Vr4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:25:03.373151"
    }
  ],
  "movies": [
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_Jlnr61dEk3c",
      "title": "Holiday",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTVkMzljMzUtZmIxMS00YWNlLTlkNDMtYmU0Nzc3MjU3OGUwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODMyODMxNDY@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Jlnr61dEk3c/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.523685"
    },
    
    
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_HVyXEbOWrp4",
      "title": "Hungama",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fb",
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTVjMWY5MGUtNjU2MS00NzgxLWJhZWUtM2VjMDE4YWRkOWFjXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODAzNzAwOTU@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HVyXEbOWrp4/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.410578"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_ye5HlqJtYKA",
      "title": "Golmaal",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Family"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fb"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYmE3YmNiM2YtM2MxMi00ZDhmLTk1ZTQtODdjOWY4YjVkYThmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDUzOTQ5MjY@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ye5HlqJtYKA/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:33.788722"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_FX3pmM7Duvs",
      "title": "Garam Masala",
      "tags": [
        "Comedy",
        "Romance"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfde923885a2149948fb"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4ZWVjY2EtYzc4NS00OWVjLTgwMmMtYTAxMDNkNDEwM2QyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODE5NzE3OTE@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FX3pmM7Duvs/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.389208"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_qdz_wO4YJFU",
      "title": "Rann",
      "tags": [
        "Drama",
        "Mystery",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff",
        "5e10bfe1923885a214994907"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjZhNzg5NTAtNTBiOC00NmI2LWI1ZDMtNzBhY2Q1ZDg5MzU3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzU0ODc1MTQ@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qdz_wO4YJFU/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:33.501221"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_Pwidjiomr9w",
      "title": "Mohejo Daaro",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Adventure",
        "Drama",
        "History"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdf923885a2149948ff"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzBhNTk0MzUtZTc4Yy00NDk3LWE1ZTItYjFmODQ4NTczMGVkL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDkxMzY0Mjk@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Pwidjiomr9w/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.666504"
    },
    {
      "movie_id": "youtube_886EXj5MXl0",
      "title": "Rakht Charitra 1",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Biography",
        "Crime",
        "Drama",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7",
        "5e10bfe2923885a21499490b"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDU1NjAxNTMxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDUzMjk4NTE@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/886EXj5MXl0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.000245"
    }
  ],
```

There are still other things involved but for the sake of simplicity I am not writing them.

The PODO file I got after generating in https://app.quicktype.io/ is below:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final homePage = homePageFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

HomePage homePageFromJson(String str) => HomePage.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String homePageToJson(HomePage data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class HomePage {
  HomePage({
    this.homeBanners,
    this.series,
    this.movies,
    this.musicCategories,
    this.musicPlaylists,
    this.publishers,
    this.liveChannels,
  });

  List<HomeBanner> homeBanners;
  List<HomeBanner> series;
  List<HomeBanner> movies;
  List<Music> musicCategories;
  Music musicPlaylists;
  List<Publisher> publishers;
  List<LiveChannel> liveChannels;

  factory HomePage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomePage(
    homeBanners: List<HomeBanner>.from(json["home_banners"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
    series: List<HomeBanner>.from(json["series"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
    movies: List<HomeBanner>.from(json["movies"].map((x) => HomeBanner.fromJson(x))),
    musicCategories: List<Music>.from(json["music_categories"].map((x) => Music.fromJson(x))),
    musicPlaylists: Music.fromJson(json["music_playlists"]),
    publishers: List<Publisher>.from(json["publishers"].map((x) => Publisher.fromJson(x))),
    liveChannels: List<LiveChannel>.from(json["live_channels"].map((x) => LiveChannel.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "home_banners": List<dynamic>.from(homeBanners.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "series": List<dynamic>.from(series.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "movies": List<dynamic>.from(movies.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "music_categories": List<dynamic>.from(musicCategories.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "music_playlists": musicPlaylists.toJson(),
    "publishers": List<dynamic>.from(publishers.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "live_channels": List<dynamic>.from(liveChannels.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class HomeBanner {
  HomeBanner({
    this.movieId,
    this.title,
    this.tags,
    this.genres,
    this.thumbnail,
    this.posterLink,
    this.platform,
    this.worldwide,
    this.createdAt,
    this.seriesId,
  });

  String movieId;
  String title;
  List<String> tags;
  List<String> genres;
  List<String> thumbnail;
  String posterLink;
  Platform platform;
  int worldwide;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String seriesId;

  factory HomeBanner.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => HomeBanner(
    movieId: json["movie_id"] == null ? null : json["movie_id"],
    title: json["title"],
    tags: List<String>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
    genres: List<String>.from(json["genres"].map((x) => x)),
    thumbnail: List<String>.from(json["thumbnail"].map((x) => x)),
    posterLink: json["poster_link"],
    platform: platformValues.map[json["platform"]],
    worldwide: json["WORLDWIDE"],
    createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["createdAt"]),
    seriesId: json["series_id"] == null ? null : json["series_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "movie_id": movieId == null ? null : movieId,
    "title": title,
    "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
    "genres": List<dynamic>.from(genres.map((x) => x)),
    "thumbnail": List<dynamic>.from(thumbnail.map((x) => x)),
    "poster_link": posterLink,
    "platform": platformValues.reverse[platform],
    "WORLDWIDE": worldwide,
    "createdAt": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
    "series_id": seriesId == null ? null : seriesId,
  };
}

enum Platform { YOUTUBE, DISCOVERYPLUS }

final platformValues = EnumValues({
  "discoveryplus": Platform.DISCOVERYPLUS,
  "youtube": Platform.YOUTUBE
});

class LiveChannel {
  LiveChannel({
    this.keyId,
    this.postContent,
    this.publisherId,
    this.publisherName,
    this.publisherProfilePic,
    this.publisherDesc,
    this.downvotesCount,
    this.upvotesCount,
  });

  String keyId;
  PostContent postContent;
  String publisherId;
  String publisherName;
  String publisherProfilePic;
  String publisherDesc;
  int downvotesCount;
  int upvotesCount;

  factory LiveChannel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LiveChannel(
    keyId: json["key_id"],
    postContent: PostContent.fromJson(json["post_content"]),
    publisherId: json["publisher_id"],
    publisherName: json["publisher_name"],
    publisherProfilePic: json["publisher_profile_pic"],
    publisherDesc: json["publisher_desc"],
    downvotesCount: json["downvotes_count"],
    upvotesCount: json["upvotes_count"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "key_id": keyId,
    "post_content": postContent.toJson(),
    "publisher_id": publisherId,
    "publisher_name": publisherName,
    "publisher_profile_pic": publisherProfilePic,
    "publisher_desc": publisherDesc,
    "downvotes_count": downvotesCount,
    "upvotes_count": upvotesCount,
  };
}

class PostContent {
  PostContent({
    this.shortcode,
    this.platformVideoLink,
    this.caption,
    this.description,
  });

  String shortcode;
  String platformVideoLink;
  String caption;
  String description;

  factory PostContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostContent(
    shortcode: json["shortcode"],
    platformVideoLink: json["platform_videoLink"],
    caption: json["caption"],
    description: json["description"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "shortcode": shortcode,
    "platform_videoLink": platformVideoLink,
    "caption": caption,
    "description": description,
  };
}

class Music {
  Music({
    this.id,
    this.country,
    this.categoryId,
    this.categoryName,
    this.categoryIcons,
    this.playlists,
  });

  dynamic id;
  String country;
  String categoryId;
  String categoryName;
  List<CategoryIcon> categoryIcons;
  List<Playlist> playlists;

  factory Music.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Music(
    id: json["_id"],
    country: json["country"],
    categoryId: json["category_id"],
    categoryName: json["category_name"],
    categoryIcons: List<CategoryIcon>.from(json["category_icons"].map((x) => CategoryIcon.fromJson(x))),
    playlists: List<Playlist>.from(json["playlists"].map((x) => Playlist.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "_id": id,
    "country": country,
    "category_id": categoryId,
    "category_name": categoryName,
    "category_icons": List<dynamic>.from(categoryIcons.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "playlists": List<dynamic>.from(playlists.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class CategoryIcon {
  CategoryIcon({
    this.height,
    this.url,
    this.width,
  });

  int height;
  String url;
  int width;

  factory CategoryIcon.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoryIcon(
    height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
    url: json["url"],
    width: json["width"] == null ? null : json["width"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "height": height == null ? null : height,
    "url": url,
    "width": width == null ? null : width,
  };
}

class Playlist {
  Playlist({
    this.playlistName,
    this.playlistDescription,
    this.playlistUrl,
    this.playlistTotalTracks,
    this.playlistImages,
    this.playlistFollowers,
    this.playlistId,
  });

  String playlistName;
  String playlistDescription;
  String playlistUrl;
  int playlistTotalTracks;
  List<CategoryIcon> playlistImages;
  int playlistFollowers;
  String playlistId;

  factory Playlist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Playlist(
    playlistName: json["playlist_name"],
    playlistDescription: json["playlist_description"],
    playlistUrl: json["playlist_url"],
    playlistTotalTracks: json["playlist_total_tracks"],
    playlistImages: List<CategoryIcon>.from(json["playlist_images"].map((x) => CategoryIcon.fromJson(x))),
    playlistFollowers: json["playlist_followers"],
    playlistId: json["playlist_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "playlist_name": playlistName,
    "playlist_description": playlistDescription,
    "playlist_url": playlistUrl,
    "playlist_total_tracks": playlistTotalTracks,
    "playlist_images": List<dynamic>.from(playlistImages.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "playlist_followers": playlistFollowers,
    "playlist_id": playlistId,
  };
}

class Publisher {
  Publisher({
    this.platform,
    this.username,
    this.fullName,
    this.profilePicUrl,
    this.content,
    this.keyId,
  });

  Platform platform;
  String username;
  String fullName;
  String profilePicUrl;
  Content content;
  String keyId;

  factory Publisher.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Publisher(
    platform: platformValues.map[json["platform"]],
    username: json["username"],
    fullName: json["full_name"],
    profilePicUrl: json["profile_pic_url"],
    content: Content.fromJson(json["content"]),
    keyId: json["key_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "platform": platformValues.reverse[platform],
    "username": username,
    "full_name": fullName,
    "profile_pic_url": profilePicUrl,
    "content": content.toJson(),
    "key_id": keyId,
  };
}

class Content {
  Content({
    this.description,
  });

  String description;

  factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
    description: json["description"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "description": description,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Service class to Parse Json
class Services {
static const String url =
"https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v2/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
"user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

```
  static Future<List<HomeBanner>> loadData() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final List<HomeBanner> homeBannerlist =
          homePageFromJson(res.body) as List<HomeBanner>;
      print(homeBannerlist);
      return homeBannerlist;
    } else {
      print("no response");
      return List<HomeBanner>();
    }
  }
}
```

In my main file where I will display the data in the initState is this :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    handleScroll(); // function which is responsible for updating the isScrollingDown variable whenever the user scrolls down
    Services.loadData().then((homeBannelList) {
      setState(() {
        _homeBannelList = homeBannelList;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the PageView of the main file.I have

```
_buildPageView(var boxHeight) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black87,
      height: boxHeight,
      child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: _items.length,
          controller: _pageController,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            try {
              HomeBanner homeBanner=_homeBannelList[index];
              return FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                image:
                    'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${homeBanner.movieId.substring(8)}/0.jpg',
                placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
            } catch (e) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            //before return Image.network('https://img.youtube.com/vi/${videoIdOfUrlList[index]}/0.jpg',fit: BoxFit.fill,);
          },
          onPageChanged: (int index) {
            _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
          }),
    );
  }
```

The relevant line is 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${homeBanner.movieId.substring(8)}/0.jpg' ,where the homeBanner thing is worked out.

[image: Error screenshot]

<<<<<<<<<<<--------Edit 1-------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>

full Json data can be found here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1saJN3MQvG55M1ipf42-65Etowi_kW80gkrosU6vBb5o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `height == null ? null : height` is useless. It should be just height.

Comment: change the datatype for ```WORLDWIDE``` from ```int``` to ```double```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why am I getting this error “Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int'” while parsing JSOn data in flutter?":

```
"WORLDWIDE": 0.0 // wordwide is a double
```

You are using an `int`:

```
int worldwide;
```

Change `int worldwide` to `double worldwide`.

Comment: Yeah ,now the error is gone.I am getting the error that                                                                       Unhandled Exception: type 'HomePage' is not a subtype of type 'List<HomeBanner>' in type cast                                                                                                                                  I tried List<HomePage> homeBannerlist =
          homePageFromJson(res.body)....But really Idont know what to do from here?

Comment: I assume that should be another question (surely an issue with the way you are parsing the `json`). You can accept the answer if it solved your original question issue.

Answer (score 1):

the `WORLDWIDE` is `double` not `int`.

```
  {
      "movie_id": "youtube_Jlnr61dEk3c",
      "title": "Holiday",
      "tags": [
        "Action",
        "Thriller"
      ],
      "genres": [
        "5e10bfdc923885a2149948f7"
      ],
      "thumbnail": [
        "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTVkMzljMzUtZmIxMS00YWNlLTlkNDMtYmU0Nzc3MjU3OGUwXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyODMyODMxNDY@.jpg"
      ],
      "poster_link": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Jlnr61dEk3c/hqdefault.jpg",
      "platform": "youtube",
      "WORLDWIDE": 0.0, // it is 'double'
      "createdAt": "2020-08-27T15:00:32.523685"
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data received from the api is float **"WORLDWIDE": 0.0,** and the Homebarner class defines it as an int;

```
class HomeBanner {
      HomeBanner({
        this.movieId
        ...
      });

  String movieId;
  ****
  int worldwide;
  DateTime createdAt;
  String seriesId;
```

Covert the int to double

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the other people answers to change int to double did work.I worked more and more on this issue and am able to successfully parse the data,The modification was to be done in the service class,actually

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterlivetv/jsonParseforHomeScreen.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart_json_web_token_generator.dart';

class Services {
  static const String url =
      "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v2/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
      "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";



  static Future<List<String>> loadDataForMovieId() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      print("response is there");
      final homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);
      print("homeBannerlist is there");
      //print("homeBannerlist is there");

       // print (homePage.homeBanners);
        HomeBanner homeBannerObject=new HomeBanner();
        List<String> homeBannerObjectMovieIdList=[];
        for(homeBannerObject in homePage.homeBanners)  homeBannerObjectMovieIdList.add(homeBannerObject.movieId);
        print("Movie ID list is there");

        print (homeBannerObjectMovieIdList);
        return homeBannerObjectMovieIdList;


    } else {
      print("no response");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

In the main file I first declared this:

```
  List<String> _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList = [];
```

This was the initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    handleScroll(); // function which is responsible for updating the isScrollingDown variable whenever the user scrolls down

    Services.loadDataForMovieId().then((movieIdList) {
      setState(() {
        _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList = movieIdList;
      });
    });

  }
```

and this was the one related to images code:

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                image:
                    'https://img.youtube.com/vi/${_homeBannerObjectMovieIdList[index].substring(8)}/0.jpg',
                placeholder: cupertinoActivityIndicator,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
```

Hope this helps.Basically it is going each level down and cascading things as list.UFFF..